# Mounting a heavy PCB in standing position

Tags: pcb

Due to space restriction I want to mount the PCB vertically and secure it with M3 screws to the box bottom like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f15QYR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

It's a power source board with a lot of big capacitors and is heavy, I'm not sure about doing it. are the capacitors going to fall off after a while? is it OK to mount a heavy PCB vertically?

Comment: You haven't given any likely operating environment.

Comment: @Transistor Inside house and room temperature. inside box temperature is going to be monitored and controlled with a fan.

Comment: @ElectronSurf is it ever in a position where it will be moved, or at risk of being dropped.

Comment: @Reroute No, it's going to sit on my desk. the only possible vibration might be from the fan, transformer or relays.

Comment: so there is never a chance it may fall off said desk?

Comment: @Reroute No, it's rarely going to be moved.

Comment: Why not attach it to the aluminum support at the top?

Comment: @Mattman944 Screws look ugly on the top but stay hidden under the box...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for this would be some rigid support rails that run up the side of the board, and ideally anchor it top and bottom to prevent how much it can flex, The top of the board is where most of the weight is, so I would strongly recommend you look for any way to make sure its secured some way at the top.

if you cannot, you will need to make up with thicker support rails, usually rectangular profile screwed to the board at the corners at minimum, more usually top bottom and center

In addition to this glues similar to the craft hot glue are used to secure each capacitor to its neighbors (a small amount in the gaps) this way they cannot work harden off the PCB